# draw a circle using html5 canvas in gwt?

Tags: java, html, gwt, canvas

I want to draw a circle in GWT, with some mouse over and drag-and-drop support. Is it possible to do so in GWT? can you provide an example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. The pseudo code will be something like this -

```
Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
Context2d context=canvas.getContext2d();
RootPanel.get(A_HOLDER_DIV_ID).add(canvas);
```

Add Handlers as follows -

1) Mouse down handler to get the start of the drag

```
canvas.addMouseDownHandler() - 
//catch the start of the circle drag, 
//clear the canvas
//Note the startx & starty
```

1) Mouse up handler to get the end the start of the drag

```
canvas.addMouseUpHandler() - 
//catch the end of the circle drag, 
//mark dragging as stopped
```

3) Mouse move handler to create the circle

```
canvas.addMouseMoveHandler() - 
//if drag started through event 1 then - 
//get x & y;
//calculate centre of circle and radius based on startx, starty and x & y above
//Clear the canvas
//And add the following code

context.setFillStyle(color);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(calculatedCenterx, calculatedCentery, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2.0, true);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

EDIT - 
Take a look at this [good example](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2338) on how to get started with GWT HTML5 canvas

Answer (score 0):

That is one approach.  The other is to use a framework such as Lienzo which abstracts all that code.  You get events, animations, and transformations out the box.  Lienzo is a graphics toolkit in Java implemented using GWT, targeting HTML5's canvas.  Lienzo is Apache 2, so it is free for all.

To do a circle using Lienzo, you would do something like:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(radius);
circle.setX(xCoord);
circle.setY(yCoord);
circle.setDraggable(true);
circle.addNodeMouseClickHandler(new NodeMouseClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onNodeMouseClick(NodeMouseClickEvent event) {
        ...
    }
});
```

There are more events you can listen to, but that one is the most common.

Good luck!